# Drupal - User Login check

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal I'm getting the error below while using the `user_is_logged_in` function. Can you help me to resolve it? I'm tying to integrate a PHP file with Drupal.

### "Call to undefined function user_is_logged_in()"

Solution: 
"PHP Filter" module provides the solution to integrate the HP code with Drupal.
Enable "PHP Filter" -> Add PHP code in node -> Select "PHP CODE" instead of Full HTML -> Save

Using Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

instead of using user_is_logged_in(), try the following:

```
global $user;
if($user->uid)
{
    // execute some code
}
```

Comment: Or you can use the globals array $GLOBALS['user']->uid